# Software Updater does not inform me of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, updates

I've searched for posts on this, but found nothing that can actually explain what is going on here.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed. I'm looking to update to 16.04.1 LTS. I have the "Software & Updates / Updates / Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" set to "For long-term supported versions", but it does not inform me of 16.04.1 LTS like it should.

Just for a test, I changed this setting to "For any new version" and it informed me of 15.10 (what about 16.04 and 16.04.1!?)

Seems like something is not working correctly here. Is anyone else seeing this behavior?

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: There are many questions about this on askubuntu.  Your question can't be closed as a duplicate because none have answers.  The only thing authoritative I have found refers to irclogs ubuntu com /2016/07/21/%23ubuntu-release dot html .  (The comment at 19:07 is full of jargon, but it says that the upgrade offer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS users shouldn't happen until at least Monday. (posted in comments at omgubuntu)

Comment: 'While Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS has been released, automatic upgrades from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will not begin until "early next week" according to the Ubuntu Release Team.' https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4tzgou/ubuntu_16041_lts_released_1404_users_see_upgrade/d5lp6s4

Comment: But why doesn't "For any new version" not find 16.04? It still shows 15.10. 16.04 has been out for 3 months.

Comment: They don't offer it up until the first point release. As the answers/comments to the many other versions of this question say, you can do it right now by `do-release-upgrade -d`